# What font is used for this "Vanity Draws Blood" text?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Really want to know what font this is:

[image]

I've tried using whatfontis.com and myfonts.com. The closest I have found is these two:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/megamistudios/semiautonomous-subunit-clade/
http://www.whatfontis.com/Chapeaux-Noirs-NF-nicksfonts.font?text=vanitydrwsblo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [In For The Kill](http://www.dafont.com/in-for-the-kill.font?fpp=100&text=VANITY+DRAWS+BLOOD):

[image: In For The Kill screenshot]

The author notes that it's "Inspired by the album cover of the musician" (though I don't know to what the author is referring to there), so this might not be the *most* correct answer. The rough edges are almost certainly something that would have happened in Photoshop after the text was set.

Comment: A bit like the 'Thin Lizzy' lock up